# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). WHILE plotting 3d graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [4, 2]


def objectivedraw(a, b, y):
    return -1 * (y[0] + 0.75 * max((1 - b) * y[0] - (y[1] + a), 0) - 0.5 * max((y[1] + a) - (1 - b) * y[0], 0) \
                 + y[1] + 0.75 * max((1 - b) * y[1] - (y[0] + a), 0) - 0.5 * max((y[0] + b) - (1 - b) * y[1], 0))


a = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.1)
b = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)  # grid of point
Z = objectivedraw(A, B,y)  # evaluation of the function on the grid

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                       cmap=cm.RdBu, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

This is the code that I am using. The part related to plotting, i.e., after defining Z was coped from https://dzone.com/articles/how-plot-function-two (second block of code on the website). I am getting an error message:

`File "C:/Users/rohan/PycharmProjects/untitled/plot utility.py", line 12, in objectivedraw
    + y[1] + 0.75 * max((1 - b) * y[1] - (y[0] + a), 0) - 0.5 * max((y[0] + b) - (1 - b) * y[1], 0))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I cannot figure out how to fix it. I think its because of my function.

EDIT: I am trying to make a Fehr-Schmidt utility function, so that's what the function is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Z = objectivedraw(A, B, y)` to work with `A` and `B` being (2D) numpy arrays, and `Z` is to be expected also a numpy array, function `objectivedraw` should be compatible with numpy. In numpy, functions on an array are executed element by element, e.g. `np.sin(A)` would have same number of elements and the same number of dimensions as `A` but with all elements replaced by their sine.

The  `@np.vectorize` decorator can make a function vectorized. To be compatible with numpy, the `max` operators should be replaced by `np.maximum`. Also, the vectorization doesn't know how to cope with the list `y`. In this case the elements of `y` can be passed one by one.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@np.vectorize
def objectivedraw(a, b, y0, y1):
    return -1 * (y0 + 0.75 * np.maximum((1 - b) * y0 - (y1 + a), 0) - 0.5 * np.maximum((y1 + a) - (1 - b) * y0, 0)
                 + y1 + 0.75 * np.maximum((1 - b) * y1 - (y0 + a), 0) - 0.5 * np.maximum((y0 + b) - (1 - b) * y1, 0))

y = [4, 2]
a = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.1)
b = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)  # grid of point
Z = objectivedraw(A, B, y[0], y[1])  # evaluation of the function on the grid

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(A, B, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                       cmap=cm.RdBu, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```